# Access the container in a Symfony2 Entity Repository that implements the security UserInterface?

Tags: symfony

I need to access the container in this special User repository.  I'm not sure how to do this without tripping over the UserProviderInterface.  Thanks for your help!

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        //the container provide the $tenantID, which I need for my query

        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.tenantid = :tenantid AND u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('tenantid', $tenantId)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {......

        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: It is better to keep your concerns separated, could you not supply the tenant ID as an argument? Perhaps post some of your other code that is calling the repository method.

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for your reply.  The problem is that the UserProviderInterface already has specific arguments.  The User Provider security layer is a bit of "magic" in Sf2, it all automatically calls the method "loadUserByUsername" and I'm not sure how to extend it.

Comment: I see your problem. Is it not possible to remove the requirement for the tenant id? The user name should already be unique removing the requirement for the tenant ID as well?

Comment: It's a multi-tenant app, so it is possible someone could have multiple accounts with the same user name.  But I think I figured it out, since we already set the tenantid on the User object when it is created, I can override getUsername() in the entity and pass an array with the username and the tenantId.  That seems to work...thank you for helping me through this!